# Byte alignment in Vala

Tags: struct, alignment, byte, vala, pack

I'm having issues with Vala adding padding to struct values.  Is there an equivalent to C's #pragma pack(1) or C#'s [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)], or possibly a workaround for this?  Thanks in advance.

~ Michael K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively. You can define your packed structure in a separate C header file with the appropriate `#pragma` or `__attribute__` and then create a VAPI binding for it.

It might be possible to abuse Vala's code generation to do it (e.g., set the `[CCode(cname)]]`, but I would advise against it.

Comment: After a bit of fiddling around with attributes, I finally managed to get this working with converting to a uint8[].  Thanks for the help :)